# how to read the current value of hardware timer in the STM32L1?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, stm32

I am trying to implement two independent tasks with the hardware timers.
I need task 1 to repeat after every 100us and the other to repeat 10us. I generated the code from STM32cubemx.
The timer function is as below

```
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void) {
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 100;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 800;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

I am further processing with the function as below :

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim-> Instance == TIM2)
    {
        ledBlueBlink();
    }
}
```

I have a task `ledGreenBlink()` which is supposed to run after every 10 times task `ledBlueBlink()` runs.
Can anyone please let me know how can I implement this?

Comment: What is frequency of APB bus?

Comment: Frequency is 32MHz.

Comment: This is the classic example of an X-Y problem: you have a need to run two tasks at an integer ratio of a time interval, you do that by counting timer interrupts not by reading back the hardware timer at subintervals.

Comment: What is it you need to do every 10us/100us?  Because 10us is a very short period to get very much done - that is the order of magnitude of a context switch for an RTOS running at 32MHz  Are you sure about your timing?  If the "tasks" are the LED blink, you will not perceive any blinking at those rates.  Better to just explain _what_ you want to do , and let someone tell you _how_ to do it, because it seems that you are over complicating this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the wording, if you're really looking for a task as I do not see a task "ledBlueBlink()".

If you just want to call "ledGreenBlink()" every ten calls of your callback, I would recommend just doing this by adding a counter variable and triggering for every ten times.

```
static unsigned counter = 0;
if (counter%10)
    ledGreenBlink();

counter++;
```

Please be aware that the counter variable needs to be static in order to preserve its value over several calls of the callback.
Futhermore it should be an unsigned type in order to safely roll over when it reaches it's maximum value.

In case you really need tasks for something you might want to clarify your code to support the question.

Comment: Hi, The task needs to be switched based on the timer values. The tasks as of now are just name sake "blinking LED's". There is nothing much happening in tasks- just led blinking. I am actually looking for a solution in which I can read the timer values, If I could read timer values- switching between tasks would be easy and more compatible for future development, Any thoughts?

Comment: @Gaurav - your approach is mistaken.  This answer is in the direction of how you actually solve such problems, effectively it is a little cooperate scheduler which schedules both a frequent and a less frequent task using a least-common-multiple time interval.   I'd probably pick something other than the modulo operator for the test though.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisStratton, that the most common way for this would be to get your self a trigger with the fastest needed frequency and then just derive down to the other frequencies. Just counting calls of the callback or implementing a real scheduler is a question of design in my pov.

I think the important part is, that you probably do not want to interfere with the timers directly. The reason is, that working on the register values directly yields some extra issues to consider. Except for special cases, you avoid this by just using the callback and calculating everything from there.